# Pyqt5: builtins.AttributeError: 'QDialog' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I converted ui file from Pyqt5 designer:

**Testing1.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 180, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 31))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Test1.py** < is meant to add methods etc. etc.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from testing1 import Ui_MainWindow

class myprog(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, dialog):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()

    test1 = myprog(dialog)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run Testin1.py it's all ok, but if run second script, test1.py, i get following message:

```
> builtins.AttributeError: 'QDialog' object has no attribute
> 'setCentralWidget'
```

I am really confused what to do, I would really really appreciate, if you could help me solve this problem. Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: [PyQt5 Docs: Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code).

Comment: Thank you. I have checked documentation before. I get errors as i have mentioned in my first post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Testing1.py* file, you create a MainWindow. 
So in your *Test1.py* file, you should change the code

```
dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
```

to

```
dialog = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
```